# Does Pixate have any sort of callback mechanism for keyframe animations?

Tags: animation, callback, keyframe, pixate

Curious as to whether or not I could subscribe to an event/notification at the end of a keyframe animation. Would anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. Found the same question on GitHub https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/issues/86